# Infinite multidimensional limits

Tags: analysis

I cannot find the definition of limit of a function of several variables involving infinity such as $(x,y) \rightarrow (0,-\infty)$

Comment: Usually, we don't work with that kind of limit, because, in general topological spaces, "limits at infinity" are related to one-point compactifications. Using that in $\mathbb{R}^n$, we would speak only of the limit with $\Vert x\Vert\rightarrow\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

There's a reason for that. In one dimension you have a clear definition of $+\infty$ and $-\infty$. However the is not so clear in higher dimensions. Consider for instance the plane. You could consider an infinite family of infinities $\infty_\theta$ in the direction $\theta$, where $\theta$ is an angle, $0\le\theta<2\,\pi$:you would be approaching infinity alogn the semi-infinite straight line $\{r\,(\cos\theta,\sin\theta):r\ge0\}$. However, this does not cover all the ways of approaching infinity: you could do it through an spiral, for instance. So, usually, only one infinity is considered in higher dimensions.

In the case you indicate, this could be a possible definition:

For all $\epsilon>0$ there is $\delta>0$ and $M>0$ such that if $|x|<\delta$ and $y<-M$, then $|f(x,y)-\ell|<\epsilon$, where $\ell$ is the limit.

Comment: Lets take some function and try to find the limit. For example $lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} xln(y), y>0$.
The question is: Can we substitute $ln(y)$, wich approaches to $-\infty$, with $t, t \to - \infty $

Comment: You said $y\to-\infty$. Now you want $y>0$. I will assume that now you want $y\to+\infty$. The limit (as I defined it) as $x\to0$ and $y\to+\infty$ does not exist. You can see this by choosing $x_n=a/n$ for some $a\ne0$, and $y_n=e^n$, which converges to $+\infty$. Then $x_n\ln(y_n)=a$ for all $n$.

Comment: Just forget everything i wrote before.
Look on this example:
$lim_{(x,y)→(0,0)}xln(y), y>0$
" Can we substitute $ln(y)$, which approaches to $−∞$, with $t,t→−∞$ " If yes, then how would you symbolize that in your notebook? (Yes, I know that it does not exist!)

Comment: You would have to explain what you mean by $\lim_{(x,t)\to(0,-\infty)}$, since it is not a standard notion.

Comment: $lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}xln(y) = lim_{(x,t)\to(0,−∞)}, t=ln(y)$ Doesn't it explains everything?
And what do you mean with "standard notion"?

Comment: Did you read what I and others wrote about infinity in higher dimensional spaces?

Comment: $t \in R$ and we can define $\infty$ there.
"You could consider an infinite family of infinities ∞θ in the direction θ". $t$ changes just in one direction. $(x,t)$ changes in all possible directions due to the different speed of convergence.

Comment: So i still don't see any troubles with $(0, -\infty)$

Answer (score 0):

There is no generic such definition since it depends on a number of issues, including the relative speeds of convergence.  For instance, consider the function

$$f(x,y)=xy.$$

Should the limit be zero, $-\infty$, $\infty$ (if $x$ is negative), or is there no limit?

So try to express both $x$ and $y$ as a function of a single index $t$ and take the limit as $t\to \infty$ (or $0$).